# XML Reader Performance

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to optimize a query and it seems that this code, specifically the XML Reader is causing the issue.

```
insert into #temp1 (Items, ApplicationId)
select distinct convert(varchar(2000),z.query('.')) Items,
xmlData.value('@IDValue', 'int') ApplicationId
from @itms.nodes('/Items/Item') as t(z)
join @itms.nodes('/Items/Item/Identification') as TRows(xmlData)
on  convert(varchar(2000),z.query('Identification [@IDType="ApplicationId"]')) = convert(varchar(2000),xmlData.query('.'))
```

This is the [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk-17goKh).

As there are 5 XML Readers I can't figure out which ones are causing the problem. Any suggestions on which ones they are and how to increase performance.

I have tried splitting the query into 2 temp tables as per Jonathan Fite's comment

```
insert into #temp1  with (tablock) (Items , ApplicationId)
select distinct convert(varchar(2000),z.query('.')) Items,
z.value('@IDValue', 'int') ApplicationId
from @itms.nodes('/Items/Item') as t2(z)

insert into #temp2 ( ApplicationId)
select distinct xmlData.value('@IDValue', 'int') ApplicationId
from  @itms.nodes('/Items/Item/Identification') as T2Rows(xmlData)
```

but the values being put in are incorrect.
The structure of the data is like this

```
<Item>
<Identification IDValue="1" IDType="AId" 
OrganizationName="Name"/>
<Identification IDValue="2" IDType="ApplicationId" 
OrganizationName="Name"/>
<Identification IDValue="3" IDType="PID" 
OrganizationName="Name"/>
<Identification IDValue="4" IDType="BID" 
OrganizationName="Name"/>
<DataHere>DataInfo</DataHere></Item>
```

I am trying to extract the ApplicationId out of the XML into the #temp1 table and I think that doing this more efficiently will speed it up.

Thanks.

Comment: Please upload the execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and add a link to it in your Post. Images do not convey all the details encoded in the plan.

Comment: I can't copy-paste the whole plan as there is sensitive data in the query text. Any suggestions on how to just copy the plan?

Comment: You can anonymize your entire plan with SentryOne's Plan Explorer (which you appear to be using already) via [these steps](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/sql-performance/anonymize-your-plans).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like you are reading the XML twice and doing a join on it.  It may be faster to read the XML into two temp tables and then join on that instead.

Comment: @JonathanFite I have tried what you said and updated the question. The ApplicationId col on table1 is all null for some reason.

Comment: can you provide some sample data here?

Comment: @ErikDarling I put up the structure. I can't use actual data though.

Comment: Is this what you are aiming to do? https://dbfiddle.uk/8Joppjr1

Comment: I’m not asking you for actual data. I’m asking you for sample data.

Comment: @MartinSmith No, I am trying to get the ApplicationId from the item into a col in #temp1.

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results for that sample data so it is clear what you are actually trying to do. The query in the Fiddle returns identical results to the initial query in the question (once I fix the provided XML to include the missing `Items` element) https://dbfiddle.uk/gnnUbndR

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing what the intended results are, but it looks like you just need to feed the first `.nodes` call into another `.nodes` using `CROSS APPLY`. This should be much more efficient than a join.

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar(2000), x1.Item.query('.')) Items,
  x2.Identification.value('@IDValue', 'int') ApplicationId
FROM @itms.nodes('/Items/Item') as x1(Item)
CROSS APPLY x1.Item.nodes('Identification [@IDType="ApplicationId"]') x2(Identification);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/VpR9RHX4)

If you can avoid the `CONVERT` and just return the XML directly using `x1.Item.query('.')` that would probably be faster also.